# How to make a page other than index.php load first for my site?

Tags: php, html, web

The title pretty much says it all. The idea is that the first page the user will be presented with will be a search field which will then send information to the main page of the site which they will be redirected to after they enter a term to search for.

UPDATE: Alright, I think I figured out what I wanted to do. It appears that what I want is a simple redirect within index.php that pushes users to that search page I mentioned.

The main part of the site is all on index.php, with the only thing in search.php being a simple search field that gives index.php information. So I just redirect users from index.php to search.php when they first visit the site, and then after they enter the search they are sent to index.php.

Hope that sort of makes sense, and maybe even helps someone.

Comment: Why not just put your search field in `index.php`? It does seem that I do not understand the thing you are trying to do...

Comment: You need to provide more information. As it is, we can only assume what you're using, so answers like "assuming you have a big red button that does this, press it" are likely to pop up. You might be lucky and have that red button, but it's kind of a waste of time.

Comment: I am not using anything fancy on the server. It is all hosted locally, in fact. I'm kind of new to the whole programming thing. The setup is really simple: just two PHP files. One for the search field and one for index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `index.php` page required a querystring parameter of `search`, you could use:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['search']) {
    header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/search.php');
}
```

You can only set headers before you have written to the output stream, so this must go before any plain text, echo statements etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Apache, you can add an `.htaccess` file on the  with `DirectoryIndex file_name`

**For Ex**

```
DirectoryIndex search.php
```